# How to identify best fit sub groups in time series data

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a set of time series user activity data where i'm trying to figure out if the user performed an action daily for at least X days in Y. My use case is 15 days in 30, doesn't have to be calendar month or anything.

There can be multiple 30 day windows per user that would qualify, and I want to know if a user has qualified multiple times and what the optimal would be.

I have looked at using pandas rolling function, but then couldn't work out how to then exclude that "window" when looking for another, or how to find the optimal, non overlapping windows.

**Example dataset**

| user_id | date | event_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-01-08 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-02-27 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-04-19 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-09 | 7 |
| 3 | 2022-04-01 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-08-07 | 1 |

Any thoughts would be great!